# ASP.net MVC download files from virtual directory

Tags: asp.net-mvc, virtual-directory

I have a virtual directory (`downloads/`) in my IIS pointing to a shared folder on another server (`\\SERVER-FILES\downloads)`.

Into this shared folder, I have files to download. This virtual directory is configured in IIS with a user who has permissions on the remote machine.

I have an action in my controller that returns the file requested:

```
string path;
return File(path, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, fileName);
```

If I specify the physical path (`\\SERVER-FILES\downloads\fileName`) doesn't work. 
I have to specify the virtual directory because is the one that has the necessary permissions to access the shared resource.

How can I specify the url (`example.com/downloads/fileName`) including the virtual directory, not the path, to download the file?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"c:\folder\myfile.txt");
string fileName = "myfile.txt";
return File(fileBytes, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, fileName);
```